# Grsync cannot connect to the server using the name@ip_address:/mnt/volume_name/

Tags: networking

This is a new installation of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  Added Grsync & setup like:

Source Field: /home/ronnie/
Destination Field: ronnie@192.168.1.250:/mnt/vzpool2/Gbackup/
Advanced Options: -e ssh

Shows no activity & gives no errors. Just does nothing.
My Laptop is setup the same way & works fine.

If I create a share drive to the Server, it works, but that share has to be in place before the process starts.  In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I used the name@ip_address...  I suspect some kind of ssh problem.

If I copy the command string that grsync produces and paste it into a command line, it works fine.

Formatted HD & installed a new copy of 18.04.1.  Still, GRSYNC will not run from the GUI. Copy the script from the GUI that failed to run, to the Terminal & it runs flawlessly.  Am I the only one using GRSYNC!?

Comment: Firewall ? Probably a client problem as the ssh server works with other clients. Try ssh from the command line and post any errors

Comment: if I copy the "Grsysc" string and aste to the command line it works fine.  It includes the ssh.  Prompt for password to the server comes up right away and, once entered, continues without any errors! Baffling!

Comment: ERROR: rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(644) [sender=3.1.2]
Rsync process exit status: 20 ... (as a result of manually stopping Grsync)

Comment: It's a permission problem somewhere.  if I "sudo su" first, then call grsync, it works!  Of course, I'm in a different directory so my scripts are not there.

Comment: It works from the terminal. No "sudo su" required!

Comment: Also runs properly in Kubuntu 18.04LTS.

Comment: I have a similar problem connection to a NAS hard drive.  Simulation runs correctly, but when I try to connect via the grsync GUI, I get an error.  Will investigate further.  grsync does start properly from GUI, using UNITY 7 on 18.04 LTS